# Why useQuery refetch always send the same parameters? How call useQuery refeatch with new parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have hook

```
export const useGetResource = data => {
  const { query = iniQuery, setNeedLoader } = data;

  const { setIsTokenExpired, isQueryEnable } = useContext(Context);

  const q = useQuery(
    ['getAssetesResource', query],
    () => {
      return ApiService.requestGql({ data: { query } });
    },
    {
      enabled: isQueryEnable,
      // refetchInterval: 1000,
      onSuccess: () => setNeedLoader(false),
    },
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (q.error === tokenExpired) {
      setIsTokenExpired(true);
    }
  }, [q.error, setIsTokenExpired]);
  return q;
};
```

And when i call it first time, with query iniQuery - it was ok.

```
const { data: resourcesData, refetch: resourceRefetch } = useGetResource({
    setNeedLoader,
  });
```

But then I need to call it again with new parameters:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setNeedLoader(true);
    if (selectedFolder) {
      resourceRefetch({
        query: `{
            getResources(resourceType:[2, 4], limit:100, folderId:"${selectedFolder?.id}") {
              id, name, resourceType, isPublic
            }
          }`,
      });
    } else {
      resourceRefetch({
        setNeedLoader,
      });
    }
  }, [resourceRefetch, selectedFolder]);
```

But the required date never comes to it. It is always called as if I call it without parameters. Why?? help me please

I am 100 percent in the right branch of the conditional operator, and 100 percent there is a correct query query. I checked it with console.log. But now new data does not come to my hook and to the function inside useQuery (It just ignores all the parameters, although it seems like it should not

Comment: refetch doesn't take parameters. please read: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-refetch